# TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in one

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, post, mongoose-schema

I am trying to use a POST request to retrieve the value of the button submitted and creates a new Mongoose model entry using the returned value before rendering a new page and passing through the value.

When i try to create the new "Type" though i receive a TypeError:
"TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in one". Can someone help me figure out what is driving the error and how to fix it?

Form Used:

```
       <form action="/round/type" method="POST" class="form-inline">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="roundType" value="one" type="submit">one</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="roundType" value="two" type="submit">two</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="roundType" value="three" type="submit">three</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="roundType" value="four" type="submit">four</button>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </form>
```

Model Schema:

```
var mongoose    = require("mongoose");

//Schema Setup  
var TypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    roundType: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Type", TypeSchema);
```

Post Request:

```
router.post("/type", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.roundType); //this console.log prints the correct value submitted
    Type.create(req.body.roundType, function(err, newType){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            res.redirect("/round/group", {roundType: newType}); 
        }
    });
});
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in one

at model.Document.$__buildDoc (/home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:222:27)
at model.Document (/home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:67:20)
at model.Model (/home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:55:12)
at new model (/home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3867:13)
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2035:51
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/node_modules/async/internal/parallel.js:27:9
at eachOfArrayLike (/home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/node_modules/async/eachOf.js:57:9)
at exports.default (/home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/node_modules/async/eachOf.js:9:5)
at _parallel (/home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/node_modules/async/internal/parallel.js:26:5)
at parallelLimit (/home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/node_modules/async/parallel.js:85:26)
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2056:5
at new Promise.ES6 (/home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:45:3)
at Function.create (/home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2019:17)
at /home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/routes/round.js:40:10
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/GolfSite_V2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Model.create`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) expects a document, or an array of documents, as the first parameter. Currently, you are just passing a string value from the POST.

Your code should look something like:

```
Type.create({roundType: req.body.roundType}, function(err, newType){
    // ...
})
```

---

The `in` operator checks to see if a property exists in an object. For example:

```
let obj = {foo: 'bar'}
console.log('foo' in obj) // true
```

In this case it is trying to find the property `_id` - which MongoDB uses as a unique identifier for a document - inside the string `one`. It cannot do this, so throws the error.